# Webservice and FMS

Tags: web-services, ssl, flash-media-server

i have prepared a multi user chat using flash media server. now i want to save that chathistory to save it in a database. for that i decided to use webservice for database connectivity. now in one of the tutorials i found that webservice will not support ssl. is it true or not. All my project had ssl v

Answer (score 0):

The [FMS docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/ssaslr/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a11afc95e-7e32SSASLR.html) say that the Server-Side ActionScript WebServices class doesn't support security features. I'd suggest asking in the [FMS forum](http://forums.adobe.com/community/flash/flash_media_server?view=discussions&start=30), though, because engineers from the team answer questions there.